# Is half the web broken for iphone users - Jquery Library cant load on iphone (safari) (javascript timeout)

Tags: jquery, iphone, timeout, mobile-safari

I recently asked a question relating to the javascript not working on my site through the iphone. Thanks to someone pointing me to the debug console on iphone I discovered this was due to Javascript execution exceeding timeout limit.

I previously had all my javascript combined in one all.js file so I decided to split it up in an attempt to pinpoint the problem - I had found some posts talking about using timouts to break up the javascript and give it a chance to catch its breath. Unfortunately in doing this I have discovered that the offending script is a minified version of jquery which is taking to long to load.

Before anyone says build a seperate mobile site - this is lots of work I dont have time to do right now but will be looking at doing later. For now I would at least expect my site using one of the most popular javascript libraries to load on one of the most popular mobile devices through a wi fi connection. Can it really be the case that the iphone cant load any website using jquery even through a wi-fi connection? Is half the web broken for iphone users.

Is there anything I can do about this?

***Solved****

****Solved****
I know the question was poorly worded and I probably shouldnt have blamed the iphone & jquery but if anyone is interested what this turned out to be it was actually down to another script used for truncating text. This script was recommended to me in response to another question I asked and is called elipses.js - it works great on desktop browsers but for some reason was upsetting iphone and iphone was wrongly pointing the finger at jquery.
Link to question with script in is http://goo.gl/PsQdt

If you have the same problem turn half your scripts off see which half stops the issue and keep narrowing down in the manner.

Comment: Would help if you posted a link to the test case - it could be a discrepency. Is the js on a CDN?

Comment: Have you tested other sites with jQuery to see if they work or not? That would seem to be the best way to answer your question. Sadly with no iPhone I can't test this for you.

Comment: link is www.alexchapman.co.uk, I will try loading through cdn see if that helps but I took it off cdn because it was causing a timeout in ie7 like this.

Comment: same result through cdn - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the jquery library and a plugin running that runs on all of the pages of my website (granted, my pages are fairly small, but still) and I haven't ever had a problem loading the website on any mobile device. I have tested it using an iPhone, iPad, Android phone, and Windows Phone 7 device. Link your website so we can see what might be going on?

Comment: This isn't an answer - this should be added as a comment. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @NickBull: I'd disagree. The question asks `"Is half the web broken for iphone users"` (in the title) and  `"Can it really be the case that the iphone cant load any website using jquery even through a wi-fi connection? Is half the web broken for iphone users."` (in the body) and this answer is saying that it does work and the internet isn't broken for iphone users. I suspect the question should have been "How can I stop this timing out" but it isn't so I think the answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Chris Good point... -1 to me for not reading the entire question properly!

Comment: Your all right -  its a poor question, and in fact if I remove all my other javascript, jquery load fine, I ahve too much loading here and will have to try to work out what i can do to solve this. Or pinpoint a better question. Thank you for prompting me to think.